# Returning Count is different for Reports for two different Profiles

Tags: reporting, custom-reports

I have created a report with Filters I got like 300 run values another Person with a different Profile has created a report with the same filters that I used but they received 250 as run values.
What Might be the reason?

Comment: Does this answer your question (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386455&type=1)